# How to extract text within flagged tags?

Tags: python, text, beautifulsoup, nlp

I have the following document and I would like to extract all categories flags.

**Input**: Should be a variable has unstructured text named `doc`.

```py
doc = "Like APC , <category="Modifier">APC2</category> regulates the formation of active betacatenin-Tcf 
       complexes , as demonstrated using transient transcriptional activation assays in APC - / - 
       <category="Modifier">colon carcinoma</category> cells. Human APC2 maps to chromosome 19p13 . 3 . 
       APC and APC2 may therefore have comparable functions in development 
       and <category="SpecificDisease">cancer</category>"
```

**Output**: Should be as follows:

```py
{
'Modifier': ['APC2', 'colon carcinoma'],
'SpecificDisease': ['cancer']
}
```

This should be automated to be able to extract all category tags in a corpus.

---

I tried the following code:

```py
soup = BeautifulSoup(doc)
contents = soup.find_all('category')
```

But didn't know how to extract each flag.

Comment: Are you sure the tags are in this format `<category="Modifier">`? This isn't valid HTML/XML...

Comment: Yes, it is. Data Source: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/CBBresearch/Dogan/DISEASE/

Comment: Which data is it on that page?

Comment: Disease corpus. Named entities are between those tags mentioned in the question above.

Comment: But that's not HTML. It's just a text file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BeautifulSoup cannot parse this type of document. But as a "workaround", you can use `re` module, for example:

```
import re

doc = """Like APC , <category="Modifier">APC2</category> regulates the formation of active betacatenin-Tcf 
       complexes , as demonstrated using transient transcriptional activation assays in APC - / - 
       <category="Modifier">colon carcinoma</category> cells. Human APC2 maps to chromosome 19p13 . 3 . 
       APC and APC2 may therefore have comparable functions in development 
       and <category="SpecificDisease">cancer</category>"""

out = {}
for c, t in re.findall(r'<category="(.*?)">(.*?)</category>', doc):
    out.setdefault(c, []).append(t)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
{'Modifier': ['APC2', 'colon carcinoma'], 'SpecificDisease': ['cancer']}
```